# How to rename property for the intermediate model for a ManyToMany field using 'through' in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I've got the following:

```
class CourseCategory(models.Model):    
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     dishes = models.ManyToManyField(Dish, through='CourseCategoryDish', related_name='course_categories')

class CourseCategoryDish(models.Model):
    coursecategory = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish)
    sort_order = models.IntegerField(default=10000)
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ordering = ['sort_order']
```

I now display my Dishes by iterating over courseCategory.coursecategorydish_set and I wonder 2 things:

1. How can I rename coursecategorydish_set to coursecategorydishes
2. Is this the best approach or is there another way to make sort_order and show accessible / useable?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for question 1:

```
coursecategory = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory, related_name="coursecategorydishes")
```

To me your approach seems to be at least logical. However, the ordering definition has to be in the Meta options:

```
class CourseCategoryDish(models.Model):
    coursecategory = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory)
    .....
    class Meta
             ordering = ['sort_order']
```

You could consider to use a PositiveIntegerField instead of the IntegerField. I am just thinking of using Grappelli and then using an inline where you can drag and drop the order of your Dishes.